# Laravel facade for model failing: Cannot redeclare class Content

Tags: php, model, laravel-4, facade

I want to add a Facade to my model named Content. But I always get the error **Cannot redeclare class Content**. Is that because the model is already loaded via the autoload? How can I fix this?

I appreciate you help, thanks.

This is how my composer file looks like

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Serviceproviders"
    ]
},
```

And this is how my Serviceprovider looks like.

```
<?php namespace App\Serviceproviders;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FormandsystemServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('content', function()
        {
            return new \App\models\Content;
        });

          $this->app->booting(function()
          {
            $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('Content', '\App\Facades\Content');
          });
    }

}
```

My Facade looks like this.

```
<? namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Content extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'content'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it, the Problem seems to be that both facade and model are named the same, which is unexpected, because it works just like this with packages but I guess this might be because of those not being autoloaded?

Anyway, my **"solution"** is the following:

1. Removing `"app/Serviceproviders"` from composer.json as I am loading this via app.php anyway.
2. Renaming my mode `ContentModel` and the file `ContentModel.php` because I want my Facade to be **Content**. This lives in the standard model folder.
3. My facade is still named `Content` and the file is `content.php` which lives in `app/Facades`
4. This is my Serviceprovider which is loaded using the app.php file

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FormandsystemServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('content', function()
    {
        return new \App\models\ContentModel;
    });

      $this->app->booting(function()
      {
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('Content', '\App\Facades\Content');
      });
    }
}
```

This works just fine I can now call `Content::getFirst()` which is a method from my content model.